# Updating text file

Tags: python, text-files, file-handling

I have just started self learning python recently and am learning text file i/o. Right now I have like a simple log-in program whereby it will update the number of times user logged in and will update the status if its more than 5 times. The function for it is as shown

```
def userDetailsUpdate(userDetails):
     userdets=[]
    userName = userDetails[0]
    userPassword = userDetails[1]
    userLoginTimes = userDetails[2]
    userCode = userDetails[3]
    if userCode == 'N':
        userLoginTimes =+1
        userDetails[2] = userLoginTimes
        if userLoginTimes == 5:
            userCode = 'O'
            userDetails[3] = userCode
    with open("userdatabase.txt", "r+") as db:
        for row in db:
            row = row.strip("\n")
            userdets.append(row.split()) 
    for everything in userdets:
                uName = everything[0]
                if userName == uName:
                    
                    break
```

this are the test data in the text file:

```
test Tester123 0 N
Tester2 Tester2 0 N
```

I want to update the details with username as the condition but im stuck as to how should i update the data in the text file, should i just put the new data into a new list and truncate it into the text file or are there any other way to update it directly using the username as the condition? (lets say i want to update the user **test**)

Comment: The easiest way for you would be to write entire file again after latest changes, a bit un optimized but will work for small and test data scenarios

Comment: Please always keep snake_case in function names, otherwise I'll have the instinct to add the JS tag to your question 

Comment: @ZainUlAbidin what about if i have a huge set of data? how do i just update the required one instead of rewriting everything?

Comment: using the offset of change location, you will only modify that line, this is efficient and recommended for large data in the file

Comment: @ZainUlAbidin alright many thanks, do you mind showing me some code examples as to how to find the offset and modifying that line?

Answer (score 0):

> *I want to update the details with username as the condition but im stuck as to how should i update the data in the text file, should i just put the new data into a new list and truncate it into the text file or are there any other way to update it directly using the username as the condition? (lets say i want to update the user test)*

I did [something identical in the past](https://github.com/Lioydiano/Briscola/blob/a5452fc0ca0f87be1540acd541ce660dc03b1308/menu.hpp#L91) and I followed this steps:

- Read the file
- Put the information into a data structure (maybe an hash map with usernames as keys)
- Elaborated the data
- Re-wrote the data from the data structure to the file

It's the slowest but the most clear way, since you're operating small amounths of data you should do it like this.

---

How to rewrite the file?

```
with open("userdatabase.txt", "w") as db:
    for user in matrix_with_users:
        for detail in user:
            file.write(f"{detail} ")
    file.write('\n')
```

Comment: so in this case, i can just add the new data into another list and rewrite the data in the text file right? pardon me im fairly new to this but how do i rewrite the file?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thougt you knew how to do it, let me update my answer.